# send data from server to client while page loads

Tags: javascript

If a Client is requesting something from the server, I want to send some extra information to the client along with the requested page. That web page is being processed by JavaScript on loading. Sometimes I require updating the DOM using the data which I have received from server. Can I get some pointers on how I can implement solution?

Comment: what type of data?? why can't you send it along with the webpage as hidden fields?? another way would be to get it from the server after the page loads using an ajax call..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question. To communicate javascript to server and server to javascript you can use signalR. For more information please see.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Generally this method is used for chat application. I think for your problem this is one the solution.

please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I thing that websocket is your best solution, of course this only will work with modern browser (not IE, just IE 10), but if you are using nodejs in server side, you can use socket.io, http://socket.io/ they say that work even in IE 5.5+